Getting an error while running my selenium project with corpdev account-Exception thrown: 'OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException' in WebDriver.dll
My Chrome driver is not launched when I open my .csproj in VS 2022 through corpdev account. When I open my project directly in VS 2022, I am able to run successfully. The error is as follows:

Exception thrown: 'OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException' in WebDriver.dll
An exception of type 'OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException' occurred in WebDriver.dll but was not handled in user code
Error starting process: C:\Users\Username\source\repos\projectname\bin\Debug\net6.0\selenium-manager\windows\selenium-manager.exe  --browser "chrome" --language-binding csharp --output

These packages are installed:
 <PackageReference Include="Selenium.Support" Version="4.23.0" />
 <PackageReference Include="Selenium.WebDriver" Version="4.23.0" />
 <PackageReference Include="Selenium.WebDriver.ChromeDriver" Version="126.0.6478.18200" />
 <PackageReference Include="Selenium.WebDriver.MSEdgeDriver" Version="126.0.2592.102" />
 <PackageReference Include="SolidToken.SpecFlow.DependencyInjection" Version="3.9.3" />
 <PackageReference Include="SpecFlow" Version="3.9.74" />
 <PackageReference Include="SpecFlow.ExternalData" Version="3.9.74" />
 <PackageReference Include="SpecFlow.Plus.LivingDocPlugin" Version="3.9.57" />
 <PackageReference Include="SpecFlow.Tools.MsBuild.Generation" Version="3.9.74" />
<!-- <PackageReference Include="SpecFlow.Plus.LivingDocPlugin" Version="3.9.57" /> -->
 <PackageReference Include="SpecFlow.xUnit" Version="3.9.74" />

I tried launching my Chrome browser thought telnet using my corpdev account. However, the Chrome driver would not launch and the above error was returned.
I have cleared caches, deleted .cache folder, bin, Obj, .vs folder, cleaned solution but this did not help.
When I run the command \selenium-manager --browser chrome from:
C:\Users\Username\source\repos\ProjectName\bin\Debug\net6.0\selenium-manager\windows>  .\selenium-manager --browser chrome

I get the following error:

[2024-07-22T07:54:51.002Z ERROR] error sending request for url (https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/known-good-versions-with-downloads.json).






Chrome Version is 126.0.6478.183 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Reduce version and check again

This issue is resolved .WebDriverManager was not installed on my project.
Link which helped:
https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/selenium_manager/#connectivity-issues

This issue is resolved .WebDriverManager was not installed on my project.
Link which helped:
https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/selenium_manager/#connectivity-issues
